# Remove first letter style

Tags: letters

I borrow a template on Overleaf for my report. However, I would like to change the first letter "N" back to ordinary letter style.

[image]

Thank you everyone!

New edition :
I am sorry for not including the code. The original code is also attached here.

```
\documentclass[11pt, titlepage]{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{wrapfig, booktabs}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{commath}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[hang]{footmisc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\newcommand{\experimentDate}{2015-2016
\author{Student}
\newcommand{\authorLastName}{Student}
\title{Title}

\date{\parbox{\linewidth}{}}

%\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{\authorLastName\ \thepage}
\lhead{\experimentShortName}
\cfoot{\className\ -- \experimentNumber}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{sectsty}

\definecolor{WordSectionBlue}{RGB}{30, 90, 147}

\allsectionsfont{\color{WordSectionBlue}}

\newcommand{\gpmol}{\si{\gram\per\mol}}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
    \section{Introduction}
    \subsection{Aim}
    \begin{paragraph}
    Nonlinear dynamics has diverse applications, ranging from medical diagnosis to computer encryption.
    \end{paragraph}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please post actual code rather than a screenshot of code, and please make sure that the code actually generates the problem behavior you're looking to fix. (The package loading instructions you're showing in the screenshot do not, by themselves, create the problem behavior.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be misusing the `\paragraph` macro. `\paragraph` is a sectioning command -- like `\section`, `\subsection`, and `\subsubsection`. `paragraph` is *not* an environment pre-defined by LaTeX. It just so happens that because of the way that LaTeX handles the (otherwise) non-existent commands `\begin{paragraph}` and `\end{paragraph}`, you're not encountering an immediate error message.

In TeX and LaTeX, paragraphs (the typographic units) are blocks of text; they do not need to be encased in `\begin{paragraph}` and `\end{paragraph}` statements.

Here's a simplified version of your code, with the `\begin{paragraph}` and `\end{paragraph}` instructions removed.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt, titlepage]{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{WordSectionBlue}{RGB}{30, 90, 147}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\color{WordSectionBlue}}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\subsection{Aim}

Nonlinear dynamics has diverse applications, ranging from 
medical diagnosis to computer encryption.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation on \begin{}. Indeed it is no need to use \begin{paragraph}.

Would you mind to point out which command was removed in my original code to recover normal text style for the first letter? It would be really helpgful =]

Comment: @Simon - The main change I made was to remove the `\begin{paragraph}` and `\end{paragraph}` statements. (I also stripped down the preamble and omitted the titlepage-related material, so that only instructions relevant to the question at hand remained.)

Comment: Removing '\begin{paragraph}' and '\end{paragraph}' reduces the text style back already. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

The command `\begin{paragraph}` is incomplete, it requires an extra argument as in

```
\begin{paragraph}{This is the title of the paragraph}
This is the text of the paragraph.
\end{paragraph}
```

Comment: Sorry. It is now corrected.

Comment: paragraph is not an environment but like \section a command which takes an argument.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer To my surprise, `\begin{paragraph}` exists and works. however, it is recommended to use `\paragraph{Title}`.

Comment: @Tom-Tom - `\begin{paragraph}` doesn't actually exist. However, it just happens to work because `\begin{paragraph}` is translated internally to `\paragraph` (and `\end{paragraph}` is translated to `\endparagraph`. Do use the syntax as it is intended, and the problem goes away automatically. Note that in LaTeX,  `\paragraph` is a sectioning header command, just like `\section` and `\subsection`; it is *not* meant to to mark off paragraphs of text.

Comment: All commands can be used as \begin{XX} as \begin{XX} calls \XX, but the outcome is not always what you would expect.